# Android bytecode analysis for method parameters

Tags: android, parameters, bytecode, dalvik, dex

I want to analyze the Android bytecode, and find all instructions that are relevant to the method parameters (kind of slicing on the parameters). Can anybody provide some references for this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Dalvik bytecode is described in detail by this document:

http://source.android.com/tech/dalvik/dalvik-bytecode.html

Possibly also of interest:

http://source.android.com/tech/dalvik/dex-format.html

(These used to live in the dalvik/docs directory in the source tree, but were "promoted".)

You can use the `dexdump` command with `-d` to generate an instruction disassembly of a DEX file and just process that.  Or you can process the DEX file yourself.

Comment: Thanks! Is there something like BCEL for Java, which I can use to analyze Dalvik bytecode more conveniently?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  The smali/baksmali tool may have some useful features though; see http://code.google.com/p/smali/ .

Comment: @user1858060 : The Byte Code Engineering Library is intended to give users a convenient way to analyze, create, and manipulate (binary) Java class files (those ending with .class). Classes are represented by objects which contain all the symbolic information of the given class: methods, fields and byte code instructions, in particular.

Answer (score 2):

Generating bytecode from .class  file to .dex is done using tool dx .

once you have example.dex file you have many tools like dexdump,dedexer,baksmali .
commands for disassembly are as follows .

dexdump -d example.dex

java -jar ddx.jar -d  
    (using dedexer)  [click here to know more](http://dedexer.sourceforge.net/)

java -jar baksmali-0.93.jar -o  <.dex file, typically classes.dex>   (using baksmali)

Best resource i ever found on internet is [this](http://0xlab.org/~jserv/tmp/dalvik.pdf)

For dalvik instruction set [click](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/dalvik/docs/dalvik-bytecode.html)

For opcodes [click](http://pallergabor.uw.hu/androidblog/dalvik_opcodes.html)